Regex: split string into sets of chars from a pool
Is there a way to describe a regex splitting a string into sets of chars from a limited pool without duplications? For example we have pool of chars (A, B, and C), so string "AABABCCAB" gets split into "A", "AB", "ABC", and "CAB", notice that the order in sets does not matter.
Thanks!
It looks like the regex should contain positive and negative lookaheads but I didn't have any success with them(((

You should specify whether the size of the pool of characters is always exactly three or something else.

@CarySwoveland Correct, ideally the pool should be assignable, i.e. you should be able to describe it with a pattern. Do you think this is doable?

Try:
([ABC])(?:(?!\1)([ABC])(?:(?!\1|\2)[ABC])?)?

See: regex101

Explanation

([ABC]): match A B or C and save to group 1
(?:...)?: then optionally

(?!\1)([ABC]): match another letter of ABC that is not the same as in group 1 and save this one to group 2
(?:...)?: and optionally match

(?!\1|\2)[ABC]: jet another letter ABC if it is not the one in group 1 or 2






I see the logic, so we continuously exclude found chars from the next input using negative lookaheads, thanks for the explanation!
